# Probability of a simple random walk

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, random-walk

Let $(X_n)$ be a simple random walk that starts from $X_0 = 0$ and on each step
goes up one with probability $p$ and down one with probability $q = 1 − p$.

Consider the case $p = 0.6$, so $q = 0.4$.

Using a normal approximation, estimate $P(16 ≤ X_{100} ≤ 26)$. You should
use an appropriate ‘continuity correction’, and explain why you chose it.
(Bear in mind the possible values $X_{100}$ can take.)

So, I have already calculated that $X_{100}$ can be distributed like so:

$X_{100}$ ~ $N(20, 96)$ since $E[X] = 20, Var(x) = 96$.

I also know that since the amount of steps is even, the value the random variable can take must also be even. So now, how can I calculate the probability given this information? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot be certain what your book would suggest for a 'continuity correction', but I would suspect it would be $$P(X_{100} \le 27.5) - P(X_{100} \le 15.5) \approx 0.454986$$

This is close to the actual probability:

$$\sum_{n=8}^{13}\dbinom{100}{50+n}(0.6)^{50+n}(0.4)^{50-n} \approx 0.458129$$

The upper bound is chosen because you want $$P(X_{100} \le 26) = P(X_{100} < 28) \approx P(X_{100} \le 27.5)$$ and the lower bound: $$P(X_{100} \ge 16) = 1-P(X_{100} < 16) \approx 1-P(X_{100} \le 15.5) = P(X_{100} > 15.5)$$

Comment: I appreciate this. Although I must question, if we are looking for a general probability, say $P(x \le X \le y)$ we would use:
$P(x \le X \le y) = P(X \le y) - P(X \le x)$

So by that logic would this question not become:
$P(X_{100} \le 27.5) - P(X_{100} \le 14.5)$ ?

Comment: Not quite. $$P(x \le X \le y) = P(X\le y) - P(X<x)$$ For a continuous random variable, this is equal to $P(X\le y) - P(X \le x)$, but for a discrete random variable, it is not equal. On the LHS, you are including the probability that $X=x$ whereas on the RHS, if you have $-P(X\le x)$, then you are removing the probability that $X = x$.

Comment: Okay, with that noted, would the answer still not change to 14.5 rather than 15.5?

Comment: For $P(X < 16) = P(X \le 16-\alpha)$ for any $\alpha>0$. This is because the discrete random variable can only take even values. So, you could probably use $$P(16 \le X \le 26) \approx P(X < 28) - P(X < 16) \approx .451346$$ But, in general, it seems to get closer when you knock it back a half a point to $$P(X \le 27.5) - P(X \le 15.5)$$ to better encapsulate the mean of 20.

Comment: In fact, $P(X \le 26.5) - P(X \le 14.5)$ is probably gonna get you even closer, as you are getting the same range of numbers ($26.5-14.5=12$, but the mean of $20$ is closer to the center of that range.